# Hakyll - How can I use the contents of a transformed file in another file transformation?

Tags: haskell, hakyll

Let's say I have this Hakyll template:

```
<h2>The archive</h2>
<p>This is an archive of all posts.</p>

<ul id="archive">
$partial("templates/post-list.html")$
</ul>
```

Now, I would like to extract the static text and put it in a MarkDown file that is rendered to HTML by Hakyll and include it in the template, like so:

```
$intro$

<ul id="archive">
$partial("templates/post-list.html")$
</ul>
```

[I found a similar question online](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hakyll/vYtcOAceIks), but it's for an older version of Hakyll.

My rough idea would be to modify the part of my `site.hs` that generates `archive.html` to include another `constField` called `"intro"` and passing it the processed MarkDown file:

```
    create ["archive.html"] $ do
    route idRoute
    compile $ do
        posts <- recentFirst =<< loadAll "posts/*"
        let archiveCtx =
                listField "posts" postCtx (return posts) `mappend`
                constField "title" "Archives"            `mappend`
                constField "intro" ???                   `mappend`
                defaultContext

        makeItem ""
            >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/archive.html" archiveCtx
            >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" archiveCtx
            >>= relativizeUrls
```

To process the MarkDown file, I'd probably have to do something like this:

```
 match "archive/intro.md" $ do
    -- route $ setExtension "html" -- No route necessary, we only want file contents
    compile $ pandocCompiler
```

But how can I load the processed file into the previous snippet?

Comment: Have you tried using [`load`](http://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/reference/Hakyll-Core-Compiler.html) or a variant of it (e.g. `loadBody`)?

Comment: @gallais That will solve it. I suggest you make an answer out of your comment.

Comment: @gallais I'll try this out this week, thanks!